# why i can't able to access my local server after getting a tunnel using ngrok?

Tags: iis, ngrok

guys please anyone can help me to solve this problem, after generating link by ngrok and when I have try to access this link  browser replay : server IP address could not be found

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following steps to solve this error:

1. Reset IPv4 settings.

   Using cmd, we can issue netsh commands to reset IPv4 settings. launch CMD prompt as administrator, and type netsh winsock reset and hit Enter. Now restart your PC. Open CMD again and type netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log and keypress Enter. Again restart your PC and check if you can connect to the internet. This will completely reset all the IP configurations and changes that we made in our system to default one for automatic resolution.
2. Flush DNS Cache.

   You can also flush the Domain Name Server (DNS) information that is cached on your system. Open cmd as admin and type `ipconfig /flushdns`, If everything is running right, you should get this as output — Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
3. Change IP and DNS settings.

   In most cases, the options are set to default. However, if you’ve made any changes or any antivirus software has deliberately misconfigured it, then you can just revert back the changes.